# bar chart of monthly temperature

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, bar-chart

I have the table below in a pandas data frame:

```
0    2017/06/04 00:00:00  31.900000  26.700000
1    2017/06/04 00:30:00  31.600000  25.000000
2    2017/06/04 01:00:00  31.400000  24.300000
3    2017/06/04 01:30:00  31.200000  24.100000
4    2017/06/04 02:00:00  30.800000  26.000000
5    2017/06/04 02:30:00  30.500000  27.000000
6    2017/06/04 03:00:00  30.300000  27.300000
7    2017/06/04 03:30:00  30.100000  27.600000
8    2017/06/04 04:00:00  29.900000  27.800000
9    2017/06/04 04:30:00  29.600000  27.900000
10   2017/06/04 05:00:00  29.200000  27.900000
11   2017/06/04 05:30:00  28.900000  27.900000
12   2017/06/04 06:00:00  30.800000  27.900000
13   2017/06/04 06:30:00  35.700000  27.900000
14   2017/06/04 07:00:00  38.300000  26.100000
15   2017/06/04 07:30:00  37.500000  25.100000
```

The table was extracted from an excel file using the following query:

```
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_excel(r\temperature.xlsx")
```

and I have analyzed them and classified them according to data and trying to group them according to the temperature with specific ranges but I do not know how to create these groups with required ranges such as <= 5C, 10 TO 20C, >= 30C).

Comment: Id advise trying something and then asking for help if you get stuck

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: I have the table below in a pandas dataframe:

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the [`cut` function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html) in Pandas might be right for your use case.  In the future, giving us code to reproduce your data frame is much better than just dumping it.  Something like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
["2017/06/04 00:00:00",31.900000,26.700000],
["2017/06/04 00:30:00",31.600000,25.000000],
["2017/06/04 01:00:00",31.400000,24.300000],
["2017/06/04 01:30:00",31.200000,24.100000],
["2017/06/04 02:00:00",30.800000,26.000000],
["2017/06/04 02:30:00",30.500000,27.000000],
["2017/06/04 03:00:00",30.300000,27.300000],
["2017/06/04 03:30:00",30.100000,27.600000],
["2017/06/04 04:00:00",29.900000,27.800000],
["2017/06/04 04:30:00",29.600000,27.900000],
["2017/06/04 05:00:00",29.200000,27.900000],
["2017/06/04 05:30:00",28.900000,27.900000],
["2017/06/04 06:00:00",30.800000,27.900000],
["2017/06/04 06:30:00",35.700000,27.900000],
["2017/06/04 07:00:00",38.300000,26.100000],
["2017/06/04 07:30:00",37.500000,25.100000]],
columns = ['time','t_high','t_low'])
```

If you want to do your analysis on one temperature column, give it a name and define the temperature boundaries you care about:

```
temps = df['t_low']
bins = [23,25,27,30]
```

Now you're ready to apply Pandas' `cut()` function, group the data by the buckets you defined, and look at some statistics.

```
temps.groupby(pd.cut(temps,bins)).describe()

          count       mean       std   min    25%   50%    75%   max
t_low                                                               
(23, 25]    3.0  24.466667  0.472582  24.1  24.20  24.3  24.65  25.0
(25, 27]    5.0  26.180000  0.732803  25.1  26.00  26.1  26.70  27.0
(27, 30]    8.0  27.775000  0.218763  27.3  27.75  27.9  27.90  27.9
```